# How to set my custom class loader to be the default?

Tags: java, tomcat, classloader

I'm trying to practice myself with custom class loaders, and I've some questions. Is there a way to indicate the JVM to use my custom class loader globally? For example, I wrote small app running under Tomcat 6. The servlet is managed by the container, where should I set my class loader? In addition, the webapp uses some 3rd party jars, can I control the classes loading of those jars?

Are the answers to the above will be different in case of standalone app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can set the system default class loader as a JVM argument:

```
java -Djava.system.class.loader
    =com.test.YourCustomClassLoader com.test.YourMainClass
```

As Tomcat starts as a java application, you can set this parameter too, at the `%TOMCAT_HOME%\bin\run.bat` or `$TOMCAT_HOME/bin/run.sh` executable.

**Edit for completion:**
If you set your classloader as de System class loader, it will be used to load Tomcat component classes, the different libraries, and your own classes. 
If you want your class loader to be used only for your application classes (including libraries and so), you should configure a `Loader` element for your context.
The Loader element must be defined inside your `Context` element, wich can be defined at a `context.xml` file.
More information:

- [Apache Tomcat: Class Loader HOW-TO](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html): defines how the ClassLoaders work in Tomcat.
- [Tomcat Configuration Reference: The Context Container](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html): how to define your `Context` element
- [Tomcat Configuration Reference: The Loader Component](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/loader.html): How to define your custom `Loader` element for your own `Context`.

Comment: For some reason it got me java.lang.Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: recursive invocation. This is what I did: subclassing ClassLoader, supplying c'tor that take a ClassLoader as parameter, configured it using the -Djava.system.class.loader, and... Boom! Error occurred during initialization of VM :-( Did I miss anything?

Comment: I have tested it with a little Main Application I have, and it's run OK.

Comment: package com.demo.presale;

public class MyClassLoader extends ClassLoader
{
 public MyClassLoader( ClassLoader parent )
 {
  
 }

 protected Class loadClass( String name, boolean resolve ) throws ClassNotFoundException
 {
  Class c = super.loadClass( name, resolve );
  
  System.out.println( "name: " + name + ", class: " + c);
  
  return c;
 }
}

Comment: And the exception:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: recursive invocation
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.initSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1312)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader(ClassLoader.java:1295)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.<init>(ClassLoader.java:228)
 at com.demo.presale.MyClassLoader.<init>(MyClassLoader.java:7)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

Comment: In my test code, the overriden Constructor calls the parent class  constructor. It checks some permissions, and sets the "initialized" attribute as  true. I have also overriden the default constructor, calling the parent constructor too: package com.test; public class MyCustomClassLoader extends ClassLoader { public MyCustomClassLoader() { super(); } public MyCustomClassLoader(ClassLoader parent) { super(parent); } /* rest of the code is quite the same as yours */ }