# Make JVM use My Own Class Loader

Tags: java, classloader

I wrote my own class loader. 
I need all my classes to be loaded using my class loader.
I have passed the VM the following: `-Djava.system.class.loader=MyClassLoader`

Only the first referenced class in my package is being loaded using my class loader.  Other classes in my package are being loaded using `AppClassLoader`.

Here is what `MyClassLoader` looks like:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class MyClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

  public MyClassLoader() {
    super(MyClassLoader.class.getClassLoader());
  }

  public MyClassLoader(ClassLoader parent) {
    super(parent);
  }

  @Override
  public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    System.out.println("MyClassLoader is loading " + name);
    return super.loadClass(name);
  }//loadClass

  @Override
  public synchronized Class<?> loadClass(String name, boolean resolve) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    System.out.println("MyClassLoader is loading " + name + " with resolve = " + resolve);
    return super.loadClass(name, resolve);
  }

  @Override
  protected Class<?> findClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    System.out.println("MyClassLoader findClass " + name);
    return super.findClass(name);
  }

  @Override
  protected URL findResource(String name) {
    System.out.println("MyClassLoader findResource " + name);
    return super.findResource(name);
  }

  @Override
  protected Enumeration<URL> findResources(String name) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("MyClassLoader findResources " + name);
    return super.findResources(name);
  }

  @Override
  protected Package getPackage(String name) {
    System.out.println("MyClassLoader getPackage " + name);
    return super.getPackage(name);
  }

  @Override
  public URL getResource(String name) {
    System.out.println("MyClassLoadergetResource " + name);
    return super.getResource(name);
  }

  @Override
  public InputStream getResourceAsStream(String name) {
    System.out.println("MyClassLoader getResourceAsStream " + name);
    return super.getResourceAsStream(name);
  }

  @Override
  public Enumeration<URL> getResources(String name) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("MyClassLoader getResources " + name);
    return super.getResources(name);
  }
}//MyClassLoader
```

I have this code in a static block in one of my classes that are being loaded:

```
  static {
    System.out.println("My class loader = " + MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getClass());
  }
```

The output of this was:

`My class loader = class sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader`

Is there a way that I can force using my class loader?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801714/how-to-set-my-custom-class-loader-to-be-the-default

Comment: @AlexK - no it is not a duplicate.  The OP clearly knows about the property, but it is not working as he expects it to.

Comment: Same issue here. Is forcing AppClassLoader possible?

Answer (score 4):

Based on what I've read, what you have done *should* work.  I suspect that the problem may be in your classloader.  Another possibility is that you haven't used the *fully qualified* classname of your classloader.

---

For the record, the javadoc for the [`ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getSystemClassLoader--)  method explains what the `java.system.class.loader` property actually does.  Read it and see if that gives any clues to the cause of your problems.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please check as I edited the question